# How to update Insert query dynamically.? sql-php-codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to dynamically add new columns and its value for new registered users.
I am trying explain you in details.

I have a query of data insert`mysqli_query($con, "Insert into tbl_name ('id', 'name') VALUES('', '".$name."')")` id is auto-increment. Now I am adding one more filed to this `tbl_name`. like `Fname` and default value is NULL. So every records got this field with `NULL` value. Now, If new user comes to website and he/she wants to join this site.then need to register.

So When they try to register, He/She gets old Insert query. But newly added column is not there in old insert query.

New query should look like this `mysqli_query($con, "Insert into tbl_name('id', 'name', 'F_Name') VALUES('', '".$name."', '".$F_Name."')")`
 So I want to update Old insert query to new dynamically, Is it possible.?

If it is possible then please tell me.

Comment: remove the old one and replace with the new code  :)   dynamically mean what you mean ?

Comment: I want to do it dynamically.? can you understand me properly. I don't wnat to maintant it by hand. It should be change with new column insert in `tbl_name`.

Comment: Yes you can, but you use CI why don't you use CI query?

Comment: Is it possible in CI then please share. I will do this with CI query. @VươngNguyễnMinh

Comment: Please read this document https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html